# Variable array dimension at runtime C++

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, runtime

I'm trying to create a program that can read some data from 2 files.
The first file is the header, that describe the data structure (dimensions, data type, extents, etc...), and the second is the raw data.

To handle different data type at runtime, I created a templated class that will be used as a container for the data. Depending on the data type read in the header, I will create a specialized class of the container to store the data.

However, now I'm facing another issue. How can I create a dynamic multidimensional array at runtime ?

I first thought doing it the old fashion way, and put a pointer into the storage class, and creating some loops ( = to the dimensionality) to create a new array (new array[size]).
But I don't think it's a very clean way of doing it.

I also thought about stacking std::vector, but I don't know the dimensionnality before runtime.

Then I considered using boost to create a multi_array, and using resize() to update the extent of my array at runtime, but it is required to know the dimension when creating the array (multi_array< type, dim > variable).
As I want to be able to access this in all my class (for future processing, etc...), I don't see how to put that in my class, as I will only know the dimensionnality at runtime.
Is it possible to create a base pointer of multi_array in my class, and declare it later (when I will know the dimension needed) ?

Or is there another way to do this ?
My final goal is to create a multidimensional array at runtime, that I can access in all my class.

Thank you.

Edit: Most of the topics I read about it are for fixed dimensional array, with a variating size. But in my case, dimension also varies.

**Update:** Your answer inspired me an idea Hugues.
I already have a templated class to read the data, but for now it only takes as parameter, the data type.
I'm thinking adding the dimensionnality to it and create a class like that:
`storageClass< data_type, data_dimension > myStorage(filename, data_extent, data_endian, data_encoding);`

This way, I can also template the dimensionnality of the data, and create a multidimensionnal array (using boost for example).
I will let you know if it worked.
Thank you.

**Update 2:** Apparently it's not possible cause templates expect constant expression. I cannot pass the variable 'dimension' (even if it's a fixed value in this case, but it's not define at compile-time).
So I guess my best option is to create a variadic getter in the custom storage class, and return the corresponding value. The problem is that a variadic method involve to parse the arguments, and as this is a method that will be frequently called, it's not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely necessary to create a custom class.
One idea is to have it contain two main members `m_dims` and `m_data`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using std::size_t;

template<typename T> class MultiArray {
 public:
    MultiArray(const std::vector<int>& dims)
        : m_dims(dims), m_data(product(m_dims)) { }
    const std::vector<int>& dims() const { return m_dims; }
    const T& operator[](const std::vector<int>& indices) const {
        return m_data[index(indices)];
    }
    T& operator[](const std::vector<int>& indices) {
        return m_data[index(indices)];
    }
 private:
    std::vector<int> m_dims;
    std::vector<T> m_data;
    static size_t product(const std::vector<int>& dims) {
        size_t result = 1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i<dims.size(); ++i) result *= size_t(dims[i]);
        return result;
    }
    size_t index(const std::vector<int>& indices) const {
        size_t v = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i<m_dims.size(); ++i) {
            assert(indices[i]>=0 && indices[i]<m_dims[i]);
            if (i) v *= size_t(m_dims[i]);
            v += size_t(indices[i]);
        }
        return v;
    }
};

int main() {
    MultiArray<float> ar{std::vector<int>{2, 3}};
    ar[std::vector<int>{0, 0}] = 1.f;
    ar[std::vector<int>{0, 1}] = 2.f;
    ar[std::vector<int>{0, 2}] = 3.f;
    ar[std::vector<int>{1, 0}] = 4.f;
    ar[std::vector<int>{1, 1}] = 5.f;
    ar[std::vector<int>{1, 2}] = 6.f;
}
```

See code in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92e597d4769f9cad

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I already have all my data in a giant buffer (single dimensional array), but now I'd like to organize them in an multi dimensional array to be able return the pointer of this multi dimensional array (e.g. with getData() ) so I can easily access these data elsewhere.
A solution would be to implement a variadic method in the storage class, like `double getData(x,y,z,c,dim5,dim6,....)` but as I might access these data a lot, I'm not sure it's optimal to do it this way.
I would prefer return a pointer to the array and access like this
`d=storage.getData(); value=d[0][0][0]...`